# Add a Field From a Lookup Column Multiple Times

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to add a field from a lookup column more than once? I have a Job list which contains a lookup field to a Job Assets list. This Job Assets list contains all the things I might need to have on a particular job, but I might need them multiple times (ie: a laborer, I might need one, or I might need 15). Currently when I add it from the left list (of all fields) to the right list (of fields I have selected) it disappears from the left list, so I can't add it again.

Comment: You mean more than 1 lookups to the same Source list? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Assuming I'm reading your question correctly, then yes. I have allow multiple selections enabled, so on the default new item form it provides a listbox on the left with all assets in my Job Assets list, two buttons to the right ("Add >" and "< Remove", and then another listbox to the right of the buttons. If I add something like "Laborer" from the left listbox to the right so that its value will be stored in the field it disappears from the left listbox. I need to be able to add the same value from the left box to the right box an arbitrary number of times.

Comment: Well its by design.. if one entity belongs to another we simply create a relationship between the two.. But if you want to add it twice, the two entries mean two different Entities (in that case it should be other list).. Does the second entry have its own attributes?

Comment: No, it is a list with one column (currently, there will be several more but they don't matter to the question). The problem is that the number of times in which the field needs to be added is entirely arbitrary. If I put each thing in 20 times the list will become completely unmanageable (there are about 50 different assets, each one could be added to a job up to 20 times). The number of assets added is also arbitrary, so I can't simply do Asset1, Asset2, Asset3, and add a column for "Number of Asset" either. A job could have one asset or it could have 100.

Comment: Take a third list, keep the Asset and Number of times used in it.. Its simply a many-to-many relationship which can be solved by taking a third entity.. It will have both the lists as lookup and an integer value that represents number of times.. But you can't show it to the end-user of course, so you might need to develop customize UI (Web parts, custom list forms, InfoPath etc.)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and is almost exactly how I would do it with a true relational database now that I think about it. One final question if you don't mind: can that custom UI be developed with just Sharepoint Designer and Sharepoint Online (Microsoft hosted Sharepoint) or do I need InfoPath/Visual Studio?

Comment: To be very honest I have very little experience with SharePoint Online.. I know it has some restrictions, so better you post another question asking the same or wait for someone else to jump-in